# Force email link to open in Facebook App browser on mobile?

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to send an email link that will open in the mobile users Facebook App browser instead of their default mobile browser. Is this possible? My site uses FB integration and I would prefer them not have to re-enter FB login info through their default browser. If they come via the FB App browser they aren't required to re-enter their FB login info. Ideas?